Have the coordinates in pixel of a Point in a Cartesian Chart
I have a Chart, and I would like to write a function that print the coordinates in Pixel of a Point in the Graph. the Coordinates in Pixels of the Point must be transform into the window coordinate system.
The Graph is generated with the library LiveChart.
Here is an example of the code to generate a Graph with this library :
XAML Code
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.CartesianChart"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Cartesian Chart Example" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <lvc:CartesianChart Name="cartesianChart1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

VB.NET Code
Imports LiveCharts
Imports LiveCharts.Wpf

Class MainWindow
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim seriesCollection As New SeriesCollection From {
            New LineSeries With {
                .Title = "Série 1",
                .Values = New ChartValues(Of Double) From {4, 6, 5, 2, 7}
            },
            New LineSeries With {
                .Title = "Série 2",
                .Values = New ChartValues(Of Double) From {6, 7, 3, 4, 6}
            }
        }

        cartesianChart1.Series = seriesCollection

        cartesianChart1.AxisX.Add(New Axis With {
            .Title = "Axe X",
            .Labels = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
        })

        cartesianChart1.AxisY.Add(New Axis With {
            .Title = "Axe Y",
            .LabelFormatter = Function(value) value.ToString()
        })
    End Sub
End Class

I have seen here, in this C# script the use of the ConvertToPixels Function.
But it always gives me (0,0) whatever the point.

can you post the code of  ConvertToPixels  part, the c# can be converted 1:1

You must project your graph to the new screen coordinate system. The most trivial case is that a Cartesian point represents a screen point. Then all you have to do is to invert the y-axis because screen coordinates start in the upper left corner.
